# Large fixed-size array inside std::tuple exhausts compiler heap in MSVC?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, compiler-errors, tuples

During the course of creating yet-another-ECS system -- essentially just a big generic struct-of-array data structure -- I've encountered a strange issue limited *mostly* to MSVC. It seems fixed sized arrays (either `std::array` or just regular arrays) stored in tuples cause the compiler to run out of heap space (MSVC Error `C1060`). The examples I've put together will build in GCC and Clang, though I've noticed that even in those situations the larger the array, the slower the build. A simple class with just a pair of arrays laid out within it does not present either issue.

A dummy code example to reproduce this is:

```
#include <array>
#include <memory>

constexpr size_t count = 10'000'000;

#define OPTION 2

class holder
{
#if OPTION == 0
    std::array<int, count> arr1;
    std::array<int, count> arr2;
#endif

#if OPTION == 1
    int arr1[count];
    int arr2[count];
#endif

#if OPTION == 2
    std::tuple<
        std::array<int, count>, 
        std::array<int, count>> 
    t;
#endif

#if OPTION == 3
    std::tuple<
        int[count], 
        int[count]> 
    t;
#endif
};

int main()
{
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<holder>();
}
```

An example of the compiler failing can be seen on compiler explorer [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ZwhSuT). The website doesn't report the actual error, but it can be seen if built locally in MSVC.

Mostly I'm curious what it is about tuples/arrays here that causes compile time and resource consumption to grow with the size of the fixed array. Why only when embedded in a tuple? Is there anything I can do design-practice-wise to ease this limitation (aside from the obvious, don't put big fixed size arrays inside tuples)?

Note that this is under C++17, though I have no real restrictions on language or modern compiler versions.

Comment: In MSVC I've noticed compilation errors along the line `arrays can't be larger than 0x7f..something` for arbritrary "large" arrays. Both larger and smaller than the actual number I've tried to allocate. And I got that as a *compilation error*. Don't know if it's related but I haven't seen that with g++ or clang++.

Comment: I've run into that 0x7FFFFFFF size limit in MSVC as well but this is something different, and starts kicking in at only 5-10 million or so.

Comment: Ok,  I got the strange limit error at both less and larger arrays so perhaps it's still that. Have you tried clang++ or g++? None have given me this strange limit.

Comment: I have and it doesn't encounter the error or exhaust the heap, but compile time seems to grow with array-within-tuple size. I'm wondering what's dependent on the array size here at compile time.

Comment: I guess templates unwinding. The only times I've encountered a sudden compile time increase is when I've made something (small) into a template. If recursive ... Zzzz...